# Laravel pivot table need to have duplicate entries

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

I am using Laravel to build a small customer list system.

I need to link COMPANY with CONTACT_PERSON. In a normal situation, I can use many to many pivot tables to link and update them.

However, I need to keep historical records.  That means the same person can act as a contact in the period earlier, resigned, and reappointed later with another period.

I try to duplicate the pivot table entries with phpMyAdmin, makes the same COMPANY linked the same CONTACT_PERSON twice, and two entries were found when retrieving the COMPANY records.
However, how can use Laravel duplicate the entries? How to use Laravel to CURD those.  Or I just do it in the wrong way?

Thank you very much!

EDIT :
Example :
Company A employed Mr. A between 01-01-2001 till 02-02-2001,
Compnay A employed Mr. A again on 03-03-2001 till 04-04-2001.
There are company B,C,D ... in company table,
There are Mr. B, C , D in the employee table too.

Use Laravel relationship pivot table to link company A to Mr. A will have two records in the above case (I need to have a historical record).

Is it the right way to handle such cases with Laravel many to many relationships?  Or I should consider other ways ?

Comment: you should provide a sample here,make other easy to understand

Comment: Dear Nay,  This is closed to a theory question.  Will the above example able illustration my question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pivot table can contain [additional columns](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#retrieving-intermediate-table-columns). You could consider adding migrations that add a `started_at` and `resigned_at` datetime field to your pivot table.

Your data structure would look something like this:

**Company**

- id
- ...

**Contact_person_company**

- contact_person_id
- company_id
- started_at
- resigned_at

**Contact person**

- id
- ...

After that, you could create functions in your model to work with the pivot columns and check for their status. A null value for the `resigned_at` column indicates that the ContactPerson is still active.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;

class Company extends Model
{
    // ... other functions

    public function contactPersons(): BelongsToMany
    {
        $this->belongsToMany(Company::class)
            ->withPivot('started_at', 'resigned_at')
            ->wherePivotNull('resigned_at');
    }

    public function resignedContactPersons()
    {
        $this->belongsToMany(Company::class)
            ->withPivot('started_at', 'resigned_at')
            ->wherePivotNotNull('resigned_at');
    }

}
```

You should define these functions as well on the ContactPerson model.

If the logic gets very complicated, consider creating a [Pivot model](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models) (CompanyContactPerson).

Please note that the combination of `contact_person_id`, `company_id` `started_at` should be unique. Otherwise, considering adding a primary key like ID the `company_contact_person` table to identify these records.

Comment: Thanks Eric, your answer of "combination of contact_person_id, company_id started_at should be unique" answered my question !!!; "adding a primary key like ID the contact_person_company table to identify these records." show me the way to solve the problem !!

Comment: Dear Eric, Thank you very much for your hins, now my problem is "contact_person_id, company_id" is not unit.
can you show me your idea of how to add contact_person_company table between them ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not understand your question. You should create a pivot table (if you haven't already) called: `company_contact_person`. Add the aforementioned functions and you should be set. You can add a `composite primary key`. However, Eloquent does not support these keys. You can consider adding an `id` to that table as well, so they become unique entries.

Comment: Dear Eric,  Your hins are very useful.  I will try to figure out the final version.  Thank you very much !